# what is the tag specification i'm missing here?

Tags: css, html, html-table, forms

this is  an assignment  given in an website.i tried my best to complete all the specifications that are mentioned in the website but i could not figure out.where my code is going wrong ?
specifications mentioned:

-

1. In addition to looking like the form shown in Figure[Bookform image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PfTgk.png), your form must include the constructs listed in the following instructions. When creating the code for your form, you must use the HTML5 tags that are appropriate to replicate the form and fulfill all the specifications listed.
2. Code the form with autocomplete active.
3. Given the image shown in Figure 1, it is easy to see that two field sets are used to create the main structure of the form. Your task is to create the field sets, including the names Customer Info and Books.Don't worry about the content fields for the moment.
4. The Name field you create should have autofocus, placeholder text, and be required. Don't forget to select the appropriate type for this field as well as all the fields that follow.
5. The Telephone field should have placeholder text, a pattern to restrict entry, and be required. Pattern should be of the type [Pattern: 1-234-567-8910]
6. The Email address field should have placeholder text and allow multiple entries. This field should also be required.
7. The Books field should have a data list. You can select the content you would like to list.
8. The Quantity (Maximum 5) field should have a minimum value of 1 and a maximum value of 5.

```html
<html>
<head>
    <title>bookform</title>
</head>

<body>

<form autocomplete="on">
    <strong> <div style='color:darkblue'> A Simple Form </div> </strong>
<br/>
<i> <div style='color:Lightblue'> Form Fundamentals </div> </i>

 <fieldset>
  <legend>Customer Info:</legend>
 <label for="Name">Name:</label>  <input type="text" name="Name" id="Name" placeholder="Enter Your Name" autofocus required/><br/><br/>
  <label for="Telephone">Telephone:</label> <input type="text"  id="Telephone" name="Telephone" placeholder="Pattern: 1-234-567-8910" pattern="[0-9]{1}-[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}" required/><br/>
 <br/><label for="Emailaddress">Email address:</label> <input type="text" name="Emailaddress" id="Emailaddress" placeholder="Enter Your Email address" multiple required/>
                  
 </fieldset>
 
 
 <fieldset>
  <legend> Books</legend>
  <input type="text" name="Books" list="countries"> <datalist id="countries">
     
     </datalist>
 <label for="Quantity"> Quantity </label> (Maximum 5): <input type="number" name="Quantity"  id="Quantity" max="5" min="1"> <br>

 </fieldset>
 
 <br>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
 
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

ERROR:testWeb(htmlpackage.WebTestBookform): 
Please check specifications for each tag
false

- image

update: when i use email type as email it is showing error hence i avoided using it.

Comment: I'm just curious, is it really `<lable>` and not `<label>` in that website?

Comment: And I think `for="Email address"` and `name="Email address"` you have to use **non-spacing** value ? Try to change to `EmailAddress` or something ?

Comment: And the `for` attribute should be equal to the `id` and not the `name` of the related element

Comment: i changed the name but it is showing the same error..

Comment: i changed lable to label

Comment: i change added id

Answer (score 2):

There are some errors in the markup and it lacks of `<!DOCTYPE html>`. You could check the code with a [validator](https://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input) first.

Comment: Since the code it's from a website, we don't really know how strict that website checks for errors. And `<!DOCTYPE html>` is not mandatory to include but is very useful so most requires it

Comment: how can we alow multiple values for email?

Answer (score 0):

Simply change `<lable ...> Quantity </lable>` to `<label>`. I think it is just typo. But be careful with `datalist` tag. It is not supported by Safari so You haven't cross browser compatibility.
[See datalist docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/datalist#Browser_compatibility)

Next:

- based on @l2aelba comment. You should use non-space value for label `for`.
- `<form>` need to got action attribute defined
- If you are using single tags like `<input> <br>` you need to use SHORTTAG. `<input /> <br/>`
- You cannot use `block` element in `inline-block`. You have used `<strong><div>...</div></strong>`. It is not valid.
- Based on @itacode answer first of all you need to use `<!DOCTYPE html>` tag because validator detect version of HTML 4.1

Comment: Check OP's comment, the error still appears even when changing `<lable>` to `<label>`

Comment: sorry when I was writing this answer whis comment was not there

Comment: how can we allow multiple values for email?

Comment: so you want to add multiple emails into one field?

Comment: yes ,when im validating as given in some answer it is giving this error:: Attribute multiple not allowed on element input at this point.

Comment: That's true. Multiple attribute does not exist. You have to do it with javascript.

Answer (score 0):

You should write autocomplete="on" instead of just autocomplete in form tag..